# Set theory: ${R^R}$ notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the meaning of ${R^R}$?
I've encountred with this notation in a presentation of Discrete Mathematics

Comment: It depends on what $R$ is.

Comment: Typically it is the set of functions $f:R\to R$, which you can think of as the set of "$R$-tuples" of elements of $R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easier to ask what $R^S$ is, which, in set theory, usually refers to the set of functions $f:S\to R$.

This notation is used because of $R$ and $S$ are finite, then $\left|R^S\right|=\left|R\right|^{\left|S\right|}$